# Trying to get MYLDAPAdmin working on Scientific Linux

Tags: linux, php, ldap

I am trying to get MYLDAPAdmin working on Scientific Linux.

I downloaded it and installed it but I am getting the following message. It looks like my PHP is not setup for LDAP. Can someone help me?

> Missing required extension Your install of PHP appears to be missing
>   LDAP support.
>
> Please install LDAP support before using phpLDAPadmin. (Dont forget to
>   restart your web server afterwards)

After adding php-ldap.. I am now getting this error

```
Unable to connect to LDAP server dvldap01.uftwf
Error: Can't contact LDAP server (-1) for user
error   Failed to Authenticate to server
Invalid Username or Password.
```

Comment: I did that but I am getting the following errors.. Unable to connect to LDAP server dvldap01.uftwf
Error: Can't contact LDAP server (-1) for user
error Failed to Authenticate to server
Invalid Username or Password.

Comment: `Invalid Username or Password` is blatantly obvious.

Comment: but if I use ldapsearch it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
yum install php-ldap
```

This will install the LDAP support module for PHP.

Comment: Restart your Apache service after the install to pick up the new module.

Comment: i did that and I double checked my ldap information but I am still getting... Unable to connect to LDAP server dvldap01.uftwf
Error: Can't contact LDAP server (-1) for user
error Failed to Authenticate to server
Invalid Username or Password.

Comment: @techsjs2012: Then you will need to configure phpLDAPadmin with the proper credentials for your LDAP server. Lookup the docs to see how this is done.